# The DIV belongs to the element, how do you know?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs with some elements in them (images, text, etc.), and I need to know which div is holding the element that was clicked. For example:

- If I click on any element in div 1, then redirect to "pagina1.php"
- If I click on any element in div 2, then redirect to "pagina2.php"

How can I do this in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the click event to all the elements inside your divs, you can find out here how to do it http://api.jquery.com/click/, you could make something like this for each div:

```
$('div#1 > *').click(function(e) {
  //This will tell you the tagname of the element that was click.
  alert($(this).tagName);

  //this will redirect you to pagina1.php might not be the best choice
  window.location.replace('pagina1.php');
});
```

And you have to do the same for div#2.

You have to notice that the selector that I made is just for the first children of the div element.

Saludos.

Comment: Binding click handlers to *all* children is something you want to avoid. Event delegation enables you to bind only one click handler on the common ancestor (the DIV in this case)...

Comment: I think your solution is better, thanks for the advice now I will improve my skills using jquery

Answer (score 4):

Just bind click handlers to the DIV's (your content wrappers):

```
$( '#div1, #div2' ).click( function ( e ) {

    this // references the DIV inside which the click occured
    e.target // references the element that was clicked

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.element-1 > *').click(function() { alert('first div childs') });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `$('').click` works for almost all HTML elements (including DIV).  This is because the event bubbles up through the chain of parent of elements.  So something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#div1").click(function() { alert("something in div1 clicked"); }
$("#div2").click(function() { alert("something in div2 clicked"); }
$("#div3").click(function() { alert("something in div3 clicked"); }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"><table><tr><td><span>blah</span></td></tr></table><div>
<div id="div2"><span>blah2</span><div>
<div id="div3"><img src=""><div>
```